# How to plug phase and neutral on this differential?

Tags: differential, circuit-protection, braking

I have replaced an old differential with this one:
[image]
[image]

Since there's no indication how/where to plug in line and neutral, can you please help?

Comment: Read the data sheet or manual for the device.

Answer (score 1):

The left part has two protected circuits. 2 pole (2p).
This means it does not care about phase or neutral. They are bridged in between with a metal pin meaning they both will trip.

The right side is a differential current protection, which does not have a marked neutral or phase, so it does not matter.

This means in this case it doesn't matter.

*Note that with many other breakers, such as 1p+N, it does matter that the protected side is phase.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does not have a neutral. In North America dedicated wire, usually called neutral, should not be interrupted. Two pole breaker for linear voltage load. Difference in phases currents trip it. Do not use if it is not approved in your country, it is dangerous.